# How do I program using cat?

Tags: bash, command-line, code-golf

In this [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/378/):
[image: Real Programmers]

they mention that real programmers use `cat`. Well, I was asking myself: how could you program using the `cat` command?

Comment: wait, you have no problem with using a magnetized needle then?

Comment: Butterfly wings are a bitch to clean from a keyboard. Let me tell ya.

Comment: Also, these answers are brutal. The effort taken to explain a joke in the geekiest way possible. +1

Comment: We don't hear of cat anymore since dog showed up! <G>

Comment: True story. I tested a beta of a text editor once (Amiga TurboText). The deal was I'd get commercial copy if I found any bugs. The cat sat on the keyboard and typed spaces until the editor crashed. The programmer (Martin Taillefer, who also coded a Modula-2 compiler) said, "wow, how did you find that one?"

Comment: I guess you're just waiting for the day when somebody writes a question "how to debug using cat".

Comment: Here's the direct link to that comic: http://xkcd.com/378/ and the title text (mouseover text) is "Real programmers set the universal constants at the start such that the universe evolves to contain the disk with the data they want."

Comment: Programing using cat: Replace your cats claws with magnetic needles. Then its just a matter of your "string playing over hard disc plates" abilites.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
$ cat > hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world.\n");
}
^D
$ gcc hello.c
$ ./a.out
Hello, world.
```

Comment: +1 hehehe. That's how!!. No fancy editing commands. ( like in ed )  BTW, I've never managed to use ed. I always wanted to, because vi took sooooo long to start from a remote terminal ( emacs was out of the question ).

Comment: I tend to use cat > to do the first pass at small test programs, because the standard Solaris vi is evil. The temptation with vi is to correct you mistakes, which is a mistakes because the cursor keys will get interpreted as escape sequences and create a mess.

Comment: Surely a REAL programmer uses "cat > a.out"

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: Obviously you need to play more Rogue, to ingrain the hjkl movement keys into your nervous system.

Comment: @chaos: This is very true. NetHack + enabling vi(m) bindings in every app that I can means that hjkl is completely ingrained.

Answer (score 37):

Nah, `echo` is clearly better:

```
echo 'main(){puts("Hello world\n");}'  | gcc -xc -
```

Even if you want to use `cat` (felines are after all wonderful), why bother putting the source to disk?  Just redirect `cat`'s output to the compiler, as in the `echo` case.

Comment: @Alex I though it was classier too. Nice pipe usage.

Comment: And you have built-in version control via .bash_history!

Comment: Too bad bash can't execute an executable coming in from a pipe, otherwise you could do it without saving the output of the compiler with something like "echo ... | gcc -xc - -o - | execute-stdin-command"

Comment: @Alex: OK, that's just f#$%ing cool!  I've actually used cat on a system to enter code before, but the echo directly to the compiler I wish I had thought of that!

Answer (score 6):

`gcc`? real programmers use `cat` *and* `xxd`:

```
$ cat | xxd -r > a.out
0000000: cefa edfe 0700 0000 0300 0000 0200 0000  ................
0000010: 0b00 0000 a803 0000 8500 0000 0100 0000  ................
0000020: 3800 0000 5f5f 5041 4745 5a45 524f 0000  8...__PAGEZERO..
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000  ................
<lot of other stuff>
0003090: 0a00 0000 0b00 0000 2000 6479 6c64 5f73  ........ .dyld_s
00030a0: 7475 625f 6269 6e64 696e 675f 6865 6c70  tub_binding_help
00030b0: 6572 005f 5f64 796c 645f 6675 6e63 5f6c  er.__dyld_func_l
00030c0: 6f6f 6b75 7000 6479 6c64 5f5f 6d61 6368  ookup.dyld__mach
00030d0: 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f4e 5841 7267 6300  _header._NXArgc.
00030e0: 5f4e 5841 7267 7600 5f5f 5f70 726f 676e  _NXArgv.___progn
00030f0: 616d 6500 5f5f 6d68 5f65 7865 6375 7465  ame.__mh_execute
0003100: 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f65 6e76 6972 6f6e  _header._environ
0003110: 005f 6d61 696e 0073 7461 7274 005f 6578  ._main.start._ex
0003120: 6974 005f 7075 7473 0000 0000            it._puts....
^D
$ chmod 755 ./a.out
$ ./a.out
Hello, world.
```

btw, I didn't know that `0xFEEDFACE` was the magic number in Mach-O binaries... cool.

Comment: It's not (judging from your listing).  It's 0xFEEDFACE (assuming the machine is little-endian).

Comment: Right! On my PowerPC machine (big endian) this is the result 0000000: feed face 0000 0012 0000 0000 0000 0002  ................

Comment: I treated it as a middle endian... getting old apparently :(

Answer (score 6):

[image: I CAN HAS PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE?]

Answer (score 4):

I think you might have missed the joke. The point is that `cat` is not an editor; it's simply a way of getting the text into the file in one go, with no editing or correcting. You write it once, and that's it.

If you're getting at something else, can you be clearer?

Comment: Vicky: I think the question is legitimate. It may not be clear how to enter text using cat ( it was not clear for me definitely ) so. I think yours would be a very good comment, but not so good answer.

Comment: Exactly what Oscar said! It didn't know how to use cat that way. I've used it to output the content of a file but it never ocurred to me you could do what user:chaos explained.

Comment: When no filename is specified, cat reads from stdin, like most other UNIX programs.

Comment: OK - I didn't realise that it wasn't commonly known that you could use cat this way! Fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

The joke is that you don't edit, you just use `cat` and perhaps (if you were going to be obtuse)... `echo`. For example:

```
echo "#stdio.h\n int main(int argc, char **argv){\nprintf(\"hello World\\n\");\nreturn(0);\n}" > helloworld.c
```

then

```
cat helloworld.c
```

repeat.

**(also, I must be bored to go and type that out)**

Comment: +1 for actually giving main its proper argument list and return value.  That's dedication.

Comment: :P , well I was going to the trouble of escaping the quotes (and even the newline in the quotes ... so why not hehe

Comment: If we're going to get really technical about it, shouldn't it be char** argv or char* argv[]?

Answer (score 4):

There's [a book available](http://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/Mastering-Cat/) on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see how far we can take this.

the output to all of these will be:

```
Hello World
```

```
$ perl -E"$(cat)"
say 'Hello World'
^D
```

```
$ test=$(cat); perl -E"$test"
say 'Hello World'
^D
```

```
$ cat | perl -M5.010
say 'Hello World'
^D
```

```
$ cat > test; test=$(cat test); perl -E"$test"
say 'Hello World'
^D
```

```
$ cat > test; test=$(cat test)$(cat); perl -E"$test"
say
^D
'Hello World'
^D
```

```
$ cat > test; test=$(cat test); perl -E"$test$(cat)"
say
^D
'Hello World'
^D
```

```
$ cat > test; test=$(cat test); perl -E"$(cat)$test"
'Hello World'
^D
```

Answer (score 1):

I've stolen the accepted and most voted answer and combined it with the echo answer, but I have added automatic conditional execution if compilation was success.

```
$ cat | gcc -xc - && ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>

main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world.\n");
}
^D
Hello, world.
```

Comment: I think the point of this question involves the `cat` utility, thus this answer doesn't qualify :D

Answer (score 0):

See Wikipedia article on Real Programmers.  You can find tutorials on the web.  Best to know assembly first (know it very well).

"Real Programmers don't use IDEs, they write programs using cat > a.out" (that is, they write machine-readable binary files from beginning to end without making any mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://rstcenter.com/forum/14753-writing-linux-programs-raw-binary.rst) post

The post is a bit out of date, as it makes certain assumptions about the location of the vsyscall page.  But if you had a copy of linux running the 2.5.53 kernel, you should be able to run something like:

```
/bin/echo -ne '\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x74\x80\x04\x08\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x20\x00\x02\x00\x28\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x74\x00\x00\x00\x74\x80\x04\x08\x74\x80\x04\x08\x19\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8d\x00\x00\x00\x8d\x90\x04\x08\x8d\x90\x04\x08\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\xb9\x8d\x90\x04\x08\xb2\x05\xe8\x90\x63\xfb\xf7\xb0\x01\xb3\x00\xe8\x87\x63\xfb\xf7\x54\x65\x73\x74\x0a' > foo.bin
chmod +x foo.bin
./foo.bin
# would print "Test"
```